# Select UIColor.systemGray2 in storyboard from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicolor

I think this is a simple question. If you wanted to select the UIColor.systemGray2 from the storyboard, is there a way to do it? I see that UIColor.systemGray is there, just don't see 2 through 6.

[image]